# Angularjs regex validation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, regex

I want to make an Angularjs regex validation that allow all alphabets, numbers, space and following special characters `! ' " & - ( )`

Comment: Try `ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s!'\x22&()-]*$/"`

Comment: I posted with an explanation below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s!'\x22&()-]*$/"
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9\s!'\x22&()-]*` - 0 or more:

  - `a-zA-Z` - ASCII letters
  - `0-9` - ASCII digits
  - `\s` - whitespaces
  - `!'\x22&()-` - `!`, `'`, `"` (`\x22` matches `"`), `&`, `(`, `)` or `-` (the hyphen must be at the end/start of the character class or escaped to denote a literal `-`)
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: This regex doesn't seem to be complete. There are symbols missing, such as `@`.

Comment: @cst1992: See the requirement: *all alphabets, numbers, space and following special characters `!` `'` `"` `&` `-` `(` `)`*. No mentioning of `@`.